# How do you quickly test C++ code?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a series of small projects (~1000 LoC each) on my own in C++. My background is in Python, where I'm used to being able to test out small changes in my code in by loading it into a jupyter notebook.

In C++, every time I change something, I have to rebuild the appropriate files and re-link, which can take around 5 seconds. After searching around on the internet, this complaint seems laughable, people talk about building their code for an hour.

But a lot of my coding process is trial and error, which is agonisingly slow in my current C++ setup.

How do you deal with this problem?

I tried using cling (C++ REPL) and its Jupyter kernel, but it seems a little immature at this point.

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/303/

Comment: You're not doing clean and build unless you have to right?

Comment: No, sir. [filler]

Comment: If the write-build-test cycle is already down to five seconds, I'd call that a win personally. I've never seen split-second build times except in personal hobby projects where one guy has total control over all dependencies and no real-world business requirements to muck it up.

Comment: My build times are very short, easily less than 5 seconds for small projects using VC++ with precompiled header (the default). I don't write much C++ code these days but I've had similar experiences with GCC. Compile times for a few thousands lines of code are trivial on a decent machine.

Answer (score 3):

I would go the unit test route.

Write a function, write a test, test it done. Change something - get if your previous test covers it, if yes you are done if not write another small test and test.

Here is a bit more information if you would like to find out some more!
http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/1.8.0/cppunit_cookbook.html#cppunit_cookbook

Answer (score 1):

The key to quickly testing in C++ is managing your dependencies so that only a small portion of your code needs to be rebuilt in order to run your tests.  There are several tricks here -- the first one is to note that the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwhCYaYDn8EgOTViYjJhYzMtMzYxMC00MzFjLWJjMzYtOGJiMDc5N2JkYmJi/view) was invented by a C++ programmer who was annoyed with exactly this problem.  The second is to remove your implementations from your general-purpose header files so that implementation changes don't trigger a rebuild of unrelated code (the [PIMPL idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom]) can help here).  Other than this, keeping modules small and ensuring that time-consuming optimizations are disabled during debugging both help quite a bit.

Comment: Now see, it pays to know *why* things were invented.  ISP is used in the Java and C# enterprise world as well, even though it has absolutely no relevance there from the C++ perspective.

Answer (score 1):

You can get very fast cycle times if you decouple what you're working on into a standalone file which is little more than a `main` and the function you're experimenting with, then set up an automated way to recompile whenever you write the file.

One way is to use your editor's abilities, like the following vim autocommand:

```
:au BufWritePost * :!gcc % && ./a.out
```

Another way if you use an inferior editor is to write a script using [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) that will wait for the file to change, then recompile and run it, then loop back to wait again.  You do get more of a history with this method as well.

Yes, you don't get the benefit of your entire application in there, but that's pretty standard for the kinds of things you typically want to try out in a REPL.